# Обновление данных таблицы jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```html
<table id="jqGrid"></table>
<div id="jqGridPager"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var template = "<div style='margin-left:15px;'><div> ID Товара <sup>*</sup>:</div><div> {idtov} </div>";
    template += "<div> Наименование товара: </div><div>{tovar1} </div>";
    template += "<hr style='width:50%;'/>";
    template += "<div> {sData} {cData}  </div></div>";

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
      url: 'tovar.php',
      editurl: 'tovaredit.php',
      mtype: 'POST',
      datatype: "json",
      colModel: [{
          label: 'ID Товара',
          name: 'idtov',
          index: 'idtov',
          width: 20,
          key: true,
          editable: false

        }, {
          label: 'Наименование товара',
          name: 'tovar1',
          index: 'tovar1',
          width: 30,
          editable: true // must set editable to true if you want to make the field editable

        }



      ],
      sortname: 'idtov',
      sortorder: 'asc',
      loadonce: true,
      viewrecords: true,
      width: 500,
      height: 200,
      rowNum: 10,
      scroll: 1,
      emptyrecords: 'Scroll to bottom to retrieve new page',
      pager: "#jqGridPager"
    });

    $('#jqGrid').navGrid('#jqGridPager',

      {
        edit: true,
        add: true,
        del: true,
        search: false,
        refresh: false,
        view: false,
        position: "left",
        cloneToTop: false
      },

      {
        editCaption: "The Edit Dialog",
        recreateForm: true,
        checkOnUpdate: true,
        checkOnSubmit: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        errorTextFormat: function(data) {
          return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
        }

      },
      // options for the Add Dialog
      {
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        errorTextFormat: function(data) {
          return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
        }
      },
      // options for the Delete Dailog
      {
        errorTextFormat: function(data) {
          return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Код редактирования

```html
<?php
if($_POST['oper'] == 'edit'){
require_once('dbdata.php');

try {
    //читаем новые значения
    $idtov = $_POST['idtov'];
    $tovarname = $_POST['tovarname'];

    
    //подключаемся к базе
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbHost.';dbname='.$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
    //указываем, мы хотим использовать utf8
    $dbh->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    //определяем количество записей в таблице
    $stm = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE tovar SET tovarname=? WHERE idtov=?');
    $stm->execute(array($surname, $idtov));
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Database error: '.$e->getMessage();
}
}
if($_POST['oper'] == 'add'){


   
    $surname = $_POST['tovarname'];
    $host="127.0.0.1";
    $user="root";
      $pass=""; //установленный вами пароль
    $db_name="mybase";
$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);

    $query = "INSERT INTO tovar VALUES ('".$_POST['tovarname']."')";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    


}
if($_POST['oper'] == 'del'){


   
    $idtov = $_REQUEST['idtov'];
    $host="127.0.0.1";
    $user="root";
      $pass=""; //установленный вами пароль
    $db_name="mybase";
$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);

    $query = "DELETE FROM tovar WHERE idtov='$idtov'";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    


}
?>
```

FireBug показывает,что ошибок нет,и запрос правильный. Удаление происходит только из грида,и при обновлении запись появляется.
Добавление и редактирование не дают вообще ничего
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 'id' != 'idtov'

Comment: Это Вы про edit? Да,ошибочка была,но работоспособность отсутствует не из-за этого

Comment: Хорошо, давайте разбираться снизу вверх. `$_POST['oper'] == 'del'`: 1. Что приходит в REQUEST - 'idtov' или 'id'? 2. Я не силен в php, но мне кажется, что запрос "DELETE FROM tovar WHERE idtov='$idtov'" будет удалять записи, у которых в поле idtov записана строка '$idtov', а не значение переменной $idtov. Таких записей, я думаю, - нет. 3. Почитайте про "SQL Injection" и параметризуйте SQL запросы.

Comment: @Igor
В другом примере я делал через $idtov = $_GET['idtov'];
Сейчас решил освоить jqGrid,но вот что-то не пошло.
В другом примере было так: href="?delete=    -  ссылка на удаление,где приписывался idtov,и через DELETE удалял `idtov` = "'.$_GET['delete'].'"
Я пытаюсь удалять не через обычные кнопки,а через средства управления jqGrid,т.е edit,add,del

Comment: Вы не ответили на пункты 1. и 2.

Comment: @Igor
1)Должен id,т.к это массив. Я Request вставил только для проверки. До этого,как и в других моих примерах для удаления был GET
2)Да,вот так idtov="'.$_GET['idtov'].'" по-идее должно удалять,но всё равно ничего не происходит. FireBug пишет OK ,и всё

Comment: Извините, мы друг друга не понимаем.

Comment: @Igor
Я понял,что при манипуляции со строками он передаёт свой id,который соответствует номеру строки,но как сделать,чтобы он передавал мой idtov,а не свой id?

Comment: У Вас правильно указано `key: true` для 'idtov', и значение jqGrid из этой колонки, только параметер в REQUEST называется `id`. Используйте `$idtov = $_REQUEST['id'];`. Еще раз обращаю Ваше внимание на пункт 2.

Comment: Спасибо,редактирование и удаление стали работать.

Comment: Ура! Примите мои поздравления. :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По рекомендации @NicolasChabanovsky.

Давайте разбираться снизу вверх.

`$_POST['oper'] == 'del'`:

1. Что приходит в REQUEST - `'idtov'` или `'id'`?
2. Я не силен в php, но мне кажется, что запрос `"DELETE FROM tovar WHERE idtov='$idtov'"` будет удалять записи, у которых в поле `idtov` записана строка `'$idtov'`, а не значение переменной `$idtov`. Таких записей, я думаю, - нет.
3. Почитайте про "SQL Injection" и параметризуйте SQL запросы.

У Вас правильно указано `key: true` для `'idtov'`, и jqGrid посылает значение из этой колонки, только параметер в `REQUEST` называется `id`. Используйте `$idtov = $_REQUEST['id'];`. Еще раз обращаю Ваше внимание на пункт 2.